# BrowseCallbackProc(), default the dialog to some member variable value instead of hardcoded value

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
BrowseCallbackProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, LPARAM lParam, LPARAM lpData)
{
    CWnd *pWnd = CWnd::FromHandle(hWnd);
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case BFFM_INITIALIZED :
            if (pWnd != NULL)
                pWnd->SendMessage(BFFM_SETSELECTION, TRUE, (LPARAM)"C:\\myFolder");
    }
    return 0 ;
}
```

Here, the value is hard-coded to `"C:\\myFolder"` but I want to replace the drive letter with some member variable, like
`pWnd->SendMessage(BFFM_SETSELECTION, TRUE,(LPARAM) myVar +":\\myFolder");`

How to acheive this?

Comment: Since you use MFC, perhaps by employing the `CString` class?

Comment: Yes its mfc and using CString class...Anyhelp how to acheive?

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly the kind of situation that the `lpData` parameter is meant for.  Set the `BROWSEINFO::lParam` field to point as your desired variable. Then inside the callback, you can type-cast the `lpData` parameter to access that variable. For example:

```cpp
int CALLBACK BrowseCallbackProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, LPARAM lParam, LPARAM lpData)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case BFFM_INITIALIZED: {
            CString path = (*reinterpret_cast<CString*>(lpData)) + _T(":\\myFolder");
            SendMessage(hWnd, BFFM_SETSELECTION, TRUE, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(static_cast<LPCTSTR>(path)));
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```cpp
CString sRootDrive = ...; // "C", etc...

BROWSEINFO bi = {};
bi.lParam = reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&sRootDrive);
...
SHBrowseForFolder(&bi);
```

Comment: below is the code for browse button click..

Comment: BROWSEINFO bi;
    TCHAR szDir[MAX_PATH];
    LPITEMIDLIST pidl;

 ZeroMemory(&bi,sizeof(bi));
 bi.hwndOwner = NULL;
 bi.pszDisplayName = 0;
 CString sRootDrive = GetYbrRootDirName();
 bi.pidlRoot = ILCreateFromPath(sRootDrive + ":\\myFolder");
 bi.lpfn = BrowseCallbackProc;  // address of callback function
 bi.ulFlags = BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS | BIF_STATUSTEXT;

 pidl = SHBrowseForFolder(&bi);
 if (pidl)
 {
  if (SHGetPathFromIDList(pidl,szDir)) 
  {
   m_editOldParent.SetWindowText( szDir);
   OnEnKillfocusOldParn() ;
  }
 }

Comment: @user16971693 and, your point is... what, exactly?. You have a `CString` variable for your root drive. Assign `&sRootDrive` to `bi.lParam`, and then inside the callback cast `lpData` to `CString*`. I have updated my example to show this.

Comment: getting error on this line   SendMessage(hWnd, BFFM_SETSELECTION, TRUE, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(path.c_str()));        i.e. class "has no member c_str()"

Comment: now getting exception on line  CString path = *reinterpret_cast<CString*>(lParam) + _T(":\\myFolder");    i.e. access violation reading location 0*000

Comment: @user16971693 that looks like a null pointer being dereferenced. Did you set the `bi.lParam` field to the memory address of `sRootDrive`?

Comment: yes i did... below is the code........BROWSEINFO bi;
    TCHAR szDir[MAX_PATH];
    LPITEMIDLIST pidl;
 ZeroMemory(&bi,sizeof(bi));
 bi.hwndOwner = NULL;
 bi.pszDisplayName = 0;
 bi.pidlRoot = 0;
 bi.lpfn = BrowseCallbackProc;  // address of callback function
 bi.ulFlags = BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS | BIF_STATUSTEXT;
 CString sRootDrive = GetYbrRootDirName();
 //bi.pidlRoot = ILCreateFromPath(sRootDrive + ":\\svn_wa");
 bi.lParam = reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&sRootDrive);
  //SHBrowseForFolder(&bi);
 GetDlgItem(IDC_BUTTON_PROJTIER)->EnableWindow(FALSE);
 pidl = SHBrowseForFolder(&bi)

Comment: @user16971693 sorry, there was a typo in my example callback, it was casting `lParam` when it should have been casting `lpData` instead. I have fixed it now.

Comment: want to do similar kind of thing in CreateProcess also..how can i acheive/
Current code: CreateProcess(exe,cmd,NULL,NULL,TRUE,NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,NULL,"c:\myFold",&si,&pi)

Desired code: CreateProcess(exe,cmd,NULL,NULL,TRUE,NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,NULL, driveLetter + ":\myFold",&si,&pi)

driveLetter is a 1 character string value coming from some method

Comment: @user16971693 Simply use a `CString` variable (or other string class) to hold the concatenated path, passing it in as a parameter, eg: `CString path = driveLetter + _T(":\\myFolder"); CreateProcess(..., path, ...);` You don't even need to type-cast it explicitly this time.

Comment: static UINT _BuildRunProcessThread(LPVOID lpvoid)    { CreateProcess()   }  createProcess() is inside the  _BuildRunProcessThread                                            
 when i try to get driveLetter from method i am getting error i.e. a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object eg CString sRootDrive = GetYbrRootDirName()

Comment: @user16971693 You are asking about things that have nothing to do with the original `SHBrowseForFolder()` issue.  Please post them separately as new questions. One question per post.